# How to add a Date Range in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server that I want to run every week which would display the data from the last 7 days.

I tried using:

```
SELECT something FROM tbl_name
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= date_col;
```

However, the above code is for MYSQL but I have SQL Server installed and I was wondering if anyone had a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT something
FROM tbl_name
WHERE date_col >= dateadd(day, -7, getdate());
```

If you want to be sure the time component is removed (as suggested by `CURDATE()`):

```
SELECT something
FROM tbl_name
WHERE date_col >= cast(dateadd(day, -7, getdate()) as date);
```

EDIT:

The answer to the question in your comment is:

```
SELECT something
FROM tbl_name
WHERE date_col >= cast(dateadd(day, -7, getdate()) as date) and
      date_col < cast(dateadd(day, 1, getdate()) as date);
```

Note the second condition is `<`, not `<=`.   If `date_col` has no time component, then:

```
WHERE date_col >= cast(dateadd(day, -7, getdate()) as date) and
      date_col <= cast(getdate() as date)
```

also works.

Comment: which one of the solutions above will have the same effect as the following:

`WHERE date_col >= '2012-04-12' and date_col<= '2012-04-18'`

Comment: What do you mean by time component?

Comment: @user3353723 . . . `datetime` versus `time`.  In MySQL, `now()` versus `CURDATE()`.

Comment: Use where date_col between '2012-04-12' and '2012-04-18' for better performance (here it includes the boundaries)

Comment: the cell value is always similar (always with 00:00:00.000 at the end) `2012-10-01 00:00:00.000` and I used to manually change the dates in the `WHERE` clause as shown by my first comment.

Comment: @user3353723 . . . Use one of the last two options.  It is best not to use `between` with dates because `between` can behave unexpectedly for dates with time values.

Comment: as far as sql server is concerned placing  2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 and 2012-10-01 in where clause  are same